# Groovy using a different value from what was initialized

Tags: groovy, jmeter

In my JMeter script i have defined a User Defined Variable i whose value is set to 1. Then i created a JSR22 pre-processor for my HTTP sample that just increments the value of i using the below code.

```
log.info(vars.get("i"));

Integer intI = vars.get("i");

intI = intI + 1;

vars.put("i", intI.toString());

log.info(vars.get("i"))
```

The problem seems to be that instead of picking up 1 as the initial value of i it is picking 49 and increment it to 50.

I was able to fix it by changing

```
Integer intId = vars.get("id")
```

to

```
Integer intId = vars.get("id").toInteger();
```

But i am curious to know what could be causing this.

Comment: The ASCII code for "1" is the value 49 - maybe that's what's happening when you try to assign without explicitly calling `toInteger()`

Comment: Aha! that's probably it.

Comment: In fact I am pretty sure that's the case: According to the docs [`var.get()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#get(java.lang.String)) returns a `String` and that gets implicitly converted to the ASCII value. You can see the behavior in the snippet: `def v = "1"; Integer intId = v; println intId`

Comment: You are correct, i do get 49 back. Do you want to put that as the answer? Kids lesson from today..always convert never depend on implicit conversion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, the conclusion from the comments as answer:

[`vars.get()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#get(java.lang.String)) returns a `String` which, when assigned to an `Integer` gets implicitly converted to the corresponding ASCII value (if the `String` is exactly 1 character, otherwise it will cause a runtime exception).

This can be observed in the snippet:
`def v = "1"; Integer intId = v; println intId` -> prints 49

Comment: It only does it if the string is 1 char long